# What to do when php session does not continue in another controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm developing a web app using codeigniter but I prefer to shy off from handling sessions the codeigniter way due to the bugs it's associated with.Therefore I'm using native php session handling. The problem I'm having is that it seems the session which is started from the default controller doesn't continue in other controllers and it's a pain in the neck. 
In both my default controller and the other controllers, I've started or continued the session way on top, before any other code like this:

```
<?php
@session_start();
```

So what do I do to make the session continue in the other controllers instead of being confined in the default controller?

Comment: remove the @. Do you get any errors?

Comment: what bugs have you experienced with the CI sessions library?

Comment: You should let the CI guys know what bugs you are experiencing: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter

Comment: Sorry guys for taking so long to respond. The bug I'm talking about is the Codeigniter Session Dissappear bug where the session ends prematurely for no apparent reason, you can google to find more about it. I tried both suggestions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MY_Controller.php in the core folder with the session start call in its construct - set this to extend CI_Controller and make your other controllers extend your newly created MY_Controller instead.

Something like:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            @session_start();
    }

}
/* End of file MY_Controller.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Controller.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the `controllers` get loaded via the main `index.php` file, you could start the session in there